# Hyperbolic Space vs Hyperbolic Plane

Tags: definition, hyperbolic-geometry

Just wondering if I can interchange the usage of the word 'hyperbolic plane' with 'hyperbolic space' or even just 'hyperbolic geometry'? Do they all mean the same?

Comment: "plane" is $2$-dimensional, "space" is $3$-dimensional, "geometry" could be arbitrary-dimensional. The terms do not all mean the same.

Comment: Every plane is a space but not every space is a plane.